# How can I resolve "javassist.CannotCompileException"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javassist, intune

I'm having trouble resolving javassist related errors.

#### Error Contents

```
Mamification failed: createFromFontInfo (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;[Landroidx/core/provider/FontsContractCompat$FontInfo;I)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi29Impl: failed to resolve types
javassist.CannotCompileException: createFromFontInfo (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;[Landroidx/core/provider/FontsContractCompat$FontInfo;I)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi29Impl: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:122)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1541)
    at com.microsoft.intune.mam.BuildTimeMamifier.mamifyClass(BuildTimeMamifier.java:451)
    at com.microsoft.intune.mam.BuildTimeMamifier.mamifyClasses(BuildTimeMamifier.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.intune.mam.BuildTimeMamifier.mamify(BuildTimeMamifier.java:109)
    at com.microsoft.intune.mam.MamifyTransformBase.transform(MamifyTransformBase.java:202)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:284)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:247)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:106)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:476)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:461)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:444)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:208)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: createFromFontInfo (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;[Landroidx/core/provider/FontsContractCompat$FontInfo;I)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi29Impl: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:119)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:458)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:440)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:118)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:177)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:116)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: android.graphics.fonts.Font
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:430)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes2(TypeData.java:439)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes(TypeData.java:410)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.dfs(TypeData.java:357)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.fixTypes(MapMaker.java:398)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:175)
    ... 109 more

> Task :app:transformClassesWithMamifyTransformForRenrakuDebug FAILED

Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: createFromFontInfo (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/CancellationSignal;[Landroidx/core/provider/FontsContractCompat$FontInfo;I)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi29Impl: failed to resolve types

Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: failed to resolve types

Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: android.graphics.fonts.Font
```

#### Code Written

Project: build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
　　　　~~
　　　　~~
　　　　~~
　　　　~~
　　　　classpath "org.javassist:javassist:3.27.0-GA"
　　　　classpath files("./com.microsoft.intune.mam.build.jar")
    }

    wrapper {
        gradleVersion = '5.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App: build.gradle

```
import ~~~~~

~~~~~
~~~~~
~~~~~
~~~~~
apply plugin: 'com.microsoft.intune.mam'

dependencies {
　~~
　~~
　~~
　~~
　implementation 'com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.10.0'
　implementation project(path: ':Microsoft.Intune.MAM.SDK')
}

intunemam {
　includeExternalLibraries = [
　　"androidx.*"
　]
}
```

#### Android Studio Version

```
4.0.2
```

#### Gradle Version

```
5.6.4
```

#### Gradle Plugin Version

```
3.6.2
```

#### SDK Version

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
```

#### Intune SDK Version

```
7.0.1
```

#### My App Info

```
Androidx compatible app
```

#### Corresponding

I put `com.microsoft.intune.mam.build` and `Microsoft.Intune.MAM.SDK.Support.v7` in the project with reference to [Microsoft Intune App SDK for Android developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-android#class-and-method-replacements).

Adding this will result in an error.

```
intunemam {
　includeExternalLibraries = [
　　"androidx.*"
　]
}
```

Please tell me how to resolve the error.